# Assembly Language Array printing

Tags: arrays, assembly

I'm having a hard time with this homework assignment. I need to print my array showing that the numbers I pulled from ReadInt are in it. I'm not sure how to do that.
Here is my code so far.

```
.data       

intarray DWORD ?

finish BYTE "Please enter a EVEN number less than 50. ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
finish2 BYTE "The entered array is: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
finish3 BYTE "The sum of the first half of the array is: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
finish4 BYTE "Please enter your numbers: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0

.code
main proc
mov edx, OFFSET finish
call WriteString
call crlf
call ReadInt
add intarray, eax
call crlf
mov edx, OFFSET finish4
call WriteString
call crlf
mov ecx,intarray
L1:
call ReadInt
mov intarray, eax
inc intarray
loop L1 
mov edx, OFFSET finish2
call WriteString
call crlf

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

I need to print my intarray to show that the number's entered by ReadInt are in it. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Too much information. You should cut down your post to keep only the essentials. This will increase your chance of getting help. For guidance, see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your way of handling the array is wrong. First of all, you've only reserved a single `DWORD` of space for your array, so if you tried to store more than one value you'd start overwriting whatever follows the array in memory (i.e. your strings). Also, `intarray` is a fixed address; `inc intarray` doesn't change where `intarray` points to. All it does it increment the first value _stored at_ `intarray`.

Comment: What type of assembler is that? Looks like Intel 8086+, except for "invoke" and "BYTE".

Answer (score 0):

Next code does what you need. The code was made with EMU8086 : it reads 10 numbers as strings (because data comes from keyboard), convert every string to number, insert them into the array, clears the screen, and displays the numbers in the array, converting every number to string (to display them). It's plenty of comments to help you understand (hope this helps you) :

```
.stack 100h
;------------------------------------------
.data
;------------------------------------------
array dw 10 dup(?)
msj   db 13,10,'Enter a number: $'
str   db 6 ;MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (5).
      db ? ;LENGTH (NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER).
      db 6 dup (?) ;CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER. 
buf   db 6 dup('$') ;WILL HOLD NUMBERS WITH 5 DIGITS OR LESS.
crlf  db 13,10,'$'
count db ? ;JUST A COUNTER FOR LOOPS.
;------------------------------------------
.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax
;------------------------------------------        
;CAPTURE 10 NUMBERS FROM USER.
  mov  di, offset array ;POINTER TO ARRAY.
  mov  count, 10 ;WE WILL CAPTURE 10 NUMBERS.
ten_numbers:
;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj
  int  21h
;CAPTURE NUMBER AS STRING.
  mov  ah, 0Ah
  mov  dx, offset str
  int  21h
;CONVERT CAPTURED NUMBER FROM STRING TO NUMERIC.
  mov  si, offset str ;PARAMETER FOR STRING2NUMBER.
  call string2number ;NUMBER RETURNS IN BX. 
;INSERT NUMBER INTO ARRAY.  
  mov  [ di ], bx ;NUMBER GOES IN CURRENT POSITION (DI).
  add  di, 2 ;ARRAY POSITION FOR THE NEXT NUMBER. MUST BE
             ;2 BECAUSE IT'S AN ARRAY OF DW (DW = TWO BYTES).
;REPEAT PROCESS.  
  dec  count
  jnz  ten_numbers ;IF ( COUNT != 0 ) JUMP.
;------------------------------------------
;DISPLAY THE NUMBERS IN ARRAY.
  call clear_screen
  mov  di, offset array
  mov  count, 10 ;ARRAY HAS 10 NUMBERS.
print_array:      
;CONVERT NUMBER TO STRING TO DISPLAY IT.     
  call dollars ;FILLS BUF WITH DOLLARS (REQUIRED TO DISPLAY).
  mov  ax, [ di ] ;MOVE CURRENT NUMBER TO AX.
  call number2string ;TAKES AX AS PARAMETER.
                     ;STRING RETURNS IN VARIABLE BUF.
;DISPLAY STRING.                     
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset buf
  int  21h
;DISPLAY LINE BREAK.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset crlf
  int  21h
;REPEAT PROCESS.    
  add  di, 2 ;NEXT NUMBER IN ARRAY TO BE DISPLAYED. MUST BE
             ;2 BECAUSE IT'S AN ARRAY OF DW (DW = TWO BYTES).
  dec  count
  jnz  print_array ;IF ( COUNT != 0 ) JUMP.
;------------------------------------------
;WAIT FOR USER TO PRESS ANY KEY.
  mov  ah,7
  int  21h
;------------------------------------------
;FINISH THE PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           
;==========================================
;NUMBER TO CONVERT MUST ENTER IN AX.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING (BUF).
proc number2string
  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
  mov  si, offset buf
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
endp  
;------------------------------------------
;CONVERT STRING TO NUMBER IN BX.
;SI MUST ENTER POINTING TO THE STRING.
proc string2number
;MAKE SI TO POINT TO THE LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.
  inc  si ;POINTS TO THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.
  mov  cl, [ si ] ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.                                         
  mov  ch, 0 ;CLEAR CH, NOW CX==CL.
  add  si, cx ;NOW SI POINTS TO LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.
;CONVERT STRING.
  mov  bx, 0
  mov  bp, 1 ;MULTIPLE OF 10 TO MULTIPLY EVERY DIGIT.
repeat:
;CONVERT CHARACTER.                    
  mov  al, [ si ] ;CHARACTER TO PROCESS.
  sub  al, 48 ;CONVERT ASCII CHARACTER TO DIGIT.
  mov  ah, 0 ;CLEAR AH, NOW AX==AL.
  mul  bp ;AX*BP = DX:AX.
  add  bx,ax ;ADD RESULT TO BX. 
;INCREASE MULTIPLE OF 10 (1, 10, 100...).
  mov  ax, bp
  mov  bp, 10
  mul  bp ;AX*10 = DX:AX.
  mov  bp, ax ;NEW MULTIPLE OF 10.  
;CHECK IF WE HAVE FINISHED.
  dec  si ;NEXT DIGIT TO PROCESS.
  loop repeat ;COUNTER CX-1, IF NOT ZERO, REPEAT.

  ret 
endp    
;------------------------------------------
;FILLS VARIABLE BUF WITH '$'.
;USED BEFORE CONVERT NUMBERS TO STRING, BECAUSE
;THESE STRINGS WILL BE DISPLAYED.
proc dollars                 
  mov  si, offset buf
  mov  cx, 6
six_dollars:      
  mov  al, '$'
  mov  [ si ], al
  inc  si
  loop six_dollars
  ret
endp  
;------------------------------------------
proc clear_screen
  mov  ah,0
  mov  al,3
  int  10H
  ret
endp
```

Maybe it's important to explain a little the variable **str**, notice the three level format, it's using 3 DBs because ah=0Ah (capture string) requires it : the first DB must indicate the max number of characters allowed, a second DB is necessary to store the length, and the third DB are the characters themselves. The string ends with ENTER (character 13), that's why the first DB is 6 (if user enters 5 characters, the sixth is ENTER).